# Reverse onItemClick event

Tags: java, android, onclick, onitemclicklistener

I have a `button` that fades in another `button` and also deletes items selected on a `ArrayList` and `ListView`. If delete a single item and go on to browse the web it recollects the urls and will display them in the `ListView`. But if I select it again(single item) it will delete it with no need to press the Delete button. I would like it that you can only delete if you press the `button`. I cant word it correctly but I believe the closest word is Reverse or Undo or maybe even Cancel. I am trying to figure it out using a variable called int click. And if(click == 1) then undo/reverse/cancel `onItemClick`.

MainActivity.Java

```
public void onHistoryClose(View view){
    FadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.fade_out);
    FadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.fade_in);
    FadeOut.setDuration(350);

    b_HistoryActivity.startAnimation(FadeOut);
    b_HistoryDeleteAll.startAnimation(FadeOut);
    b_HistoryActivity.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    b_HistoryList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if(b_HistoryActivity.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
        w_Toolbar.startAnimation(FadeIn);
        bottomNav.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    if(click == 1){

    }
}
public void onHistoryDelete(View view){
    click = 1;
    Toast delete = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Select to Delete",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    delete.show();
    b_HistoryList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            String item = HistoryAdapter.getItem(position);
            HistoryAdapter.deleteItem(item);
            HistoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            view.getFocusables(position);
            view.setSelected(true);
        }
    });
    b_HistoryDeleteAll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    FadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.fade_in);
    b_HistoryDeleteAll.startAnimation(FadeIn);
}
```

Comment: Can you try to clarify your question more. It's bit unclear currently

Comment: @VivekMishra I want it to reset the onclick event, when I use the browser it collects every url that goes through. Once i go to delete the url from the history page i have to click a button then it will allow me to. but if i click it then go back later to delete more i dont have to press it. How can i make it that i have to press the button a second time